# Class is giving output even when a variable is not defined globally

Tags: python, python-2.7, class

Define a class which will have `getstring()` to input a string and `printstring()` convert it in uppercase and another function to use `__init__`

```
class a:
    def __init__(self,b,c):
        self.b=b
        self.c=c
    def getstring(self):
        print "Please enter input"
        self.x=raw_input()
        return x
    def printstring(self):
        y=self.x.upper()
        return y
    def sum(self):
        c=self.c+self.b
        return c
d=a(23,53)
d.getstring()
d.printstring()
```

The result is that the input string should be converted to uppercase. This code is working but it shouldn't as x doesn't have global scope.

Another weird thing is that if in the above code, the 'sum' function is called then the input string is not converted to upper case. It will just print the string as given in input and will give the sum.

Comment: `self.x` is having the class scope so it worked with class object. Whatever you are accessing with `self` is having class scope. And they are available with class object

Comment: but why doesn't it work if i call sum, if i had included another line- d.sum() then it doesn't convert to uppercase

Comment: Because converting to `uppercase` is written in `printstring` not inside `sum`

Comment: what i meant was if i call getstring, printstring and sum then the uppercase does'nt work.

Comment: It will not work like that. Atleast you have to call `printstring` inside `sum`

Answer (score 0):

To get uppercased result change your `getstring` function like this:

```py
def getstring(self):
    print "Please enter input"
    self.x=raw_input().upper()
    return x
```

You need to assign the `str.upper()` result in the variable, `upper()` method doesn't work inplace

Comment: my doubt was why did it give an error when I included d.sum() and it works without d.sum()

Comment: @PrejithAlex what kind of error? please elaborate or post some stack traces

Answer (score 0):

> This code is working but it shouldn't as x doesn't have global scope.

x from the gettering function does not have a global scope, but self.x does, it goes with the object and you don't need to global it.

> Another weird thing is that if in the above code, the 'sum' function is called then the input string is not converted to upper case. It will just print the string as given in input and will give the sum.

It still turns it into the upper case on my pc, I think it might be because you are using python 2.7 and I'm on 3.6. I suggest you switch now if you don't have a lot of projects done already because many libraries are not compatible with 2.7